# Query not working using node.js node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Whats wrong with my query? im having this error: 
[image]

```
con.query(
           'SELECT nick FROM channels WHERE room=1room',
           function(err, rows) {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log(rows);
           }
       );
```

I tried this, and i have the same error:

```
var room = "1room";
       con.query(
           'SELECT nick FROM channels WHERE room=' + room,
           function(err, rows) {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log(rows);
           }
       );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is treating `1room` as a variable, not a string. Wrap it in quotes and it should work.

```
con.query(
   'SELECT nick FROM channels WHERE room="1room"',
   function(err, rows) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(rows);
   }
);
```

For your second example, you should get in the habit of [escaping the variables](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) you use in queries for security reasons (to prevent SQL injection).

```
var room = "1room";
con.query(
   'SELECT nick FROM channels WHERE room=?',
   [room],
   function(err, rows) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(rows);
   }
);
```